# Changing the minimum value for bullet chart in sparklines R package

Tags: r, sparklines

I'd like to add a minimum value to a bullet graph using the `sparklines` R package. The default sets the minimum value to be 0.

```
sparkline(c(30,15), type = "bullet")
```

With chartRangeMin:

[image: with chartRangeMin]

Following the documentation for the original jquery here: https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#common,  I tried `chartRangeMin`:

```
sparkline(c(30,15), type = "bullet", chartRangeMin = 10)
```

but it appears to produce the same result as if we didn’t have this parameter

Without chartRangeMin:

[image]

How do I add a minimum value for the bullet graph?

Answer (score 1):

Upon looking at the [JS github code](https://github.com/gwatts/jquery.sparkline/blob/657f42892ee384691e2540fae1f04058da4145d5/src/defaults.js#L94) which is the base for the sparklines API for R, I discovered that the default minimum value for bullet graphs is set by a `base` variable.

To create the above bullet graph with a minimum of 10:

```
sparkline(c(30, 15), type = "bullet", base = 10)
```

[With base parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w98yN.png)